# Uploading a InfoPath form shows as Upgrading as status for a long time

Tags: infopath, forms-services

After uploading a form under  manage form templates under central admin, i am getting the status as "Upgrading" for a day.. The form is not getting upgraded.

All the application pools are running. Checked the timer and administration service under services.msc, they are also started.

I checked the below link: sharenotes.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/infopath-managed

But the solution in that did not help.

I also tried this:  going to 14 bin in cmd prompt and then running the below command:

stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs

I got the message as: The administration service is running so all administration jobs will be run in the timer service.

How to fix this form template uploading issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Open Central Administration and go to **Operations**/ **Timer Job Definitions**

Find your form template job and delete it.
Then click **Manage form templates** on **Application Management** tab.
Refresh this page. Probably it shows your form template that it is ready.

I know this is not a real solution, but it saves time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is on a development server, can you try restarting the SharePoint timer job in services.msc? Is this just for one Infopath form or all of them in the farm?

Comment: It is in dev environment. i have restarted the services. still the same error. It is happening for all forms.